# How to handle more than 100 classes through Polymorphism without violating Open Closed Principle

Tags: oop

Suppose I have a class called A and there are two versions to it A1 and A2.

```
class A{};

class A1 : A{};

class A2 : A{};
```

and I have one more class which would use these.

```
class B
{
  B(A obj)
  {

   if(obj.type(A1)){}//do this

   else(obj.type(A2)){})//do this

  }
}
```

Questions:

1) Suppose there are 100 or 1000 of classes derived from A,then how do I implement it in the constructor of B, by using "switch" or "if"> In both cases if I have to extend the class I will violate the "open closed principle".

2) `if(obj.type(A1))` is this implementation the best way to implement for detecting which class object is there.

Comment: Which language are we talking about?

Comment: i think the concept would remain same for any language,Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Not necessarily, while there are general patterns that can be used in most OO languages, different languages have different facilities. Some might have multiple inheritance for example, others may have traits and so on.

Comment: Please explain about the Class A and A1 and A2 ... 's structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 100 classes derived from the same base class, you need to re-consider your design.

That said, sometimes you have a large number of classes doing similar things.

One option is to use an `interface`, have your different classes implement that interface, and the "do this" implemented in each subclass separately:

```
class B { B(A obj) {

if(obj.type(A1)){}//do this

else(obj.type(A2)){})//do this

} }
```

becomes

```
interface AInterface
{
   public void doThis();
}

abstract class A implements AInterface
{
   ...
}

class A1 extends A 
{
   public void doThis()
   {
      ...
   }
}

class A2 extends A 
{
   public void doThis()
   {
      ...
   }
}

class B { B(AInterface obj) {

    obj.doThis();

} }
```

Another, more advanced approach is to use the [Visitor design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Suppose there is some logic which has to be written in B class function and that logic depends on the type of class it is getting in the interface object i.e. if its A1 object logic will be different and if its A2 logic will be different,how do we solve it .